# Why is my token being rejected? What is a resource ID? "Invalid token does not contain resource id (oauth2-resource)"

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to configure OAuth2 for a spring project. I'm using a shared UAA ([oauth implementation from cloud foundry](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/api/uaa/version/4.8.0)) instance my work place provides (so I'm not trying to create an authorization server and the authorization server is separate from the resource server). The frontend is a single-page-application and it gets token directly from the authorization server using the implicit grant. I have the SPA setup where it adds the `Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>` header on each web API call to microservices.

My issue is now with the microservices.

I'm trying to use this shared authorization server to authenticate the microservices. I might have a misunderstanding here, buy my current understanding is that these microservices play the role of the resource server because they host the endpoints the SPA uses to get data.

So I tried to configure a microservice like so:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class OAuth2ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setVerifierKey("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----<key omitted>-----END PUBLIC KEY-----");
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
         resources.tokenServices(tokenServices());
    }
}
```

Now whenever I hit a `/api/**` with the `Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>`, I get a `403` with this error:

```
{
    "error": "access_denied",
    "error_description": "Invalid token does not contain resource id (oauth2-resource)"
}
```

---

### So here are my questions:

- **How do I configure these microservices to validate the token and insert a [`Principal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Principal.html) in controller methods?** I currently have it setup where the SPA has and sends the token and I also have the public key used to verify the signature of the token. I have also used [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) to test the token and it says "Signature Verified".
- What is a resource id? Why do I need it and why does it cause the error above? Is that a Spring only thing??

Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Spring OAuth expects "aud" [claim](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-tschofenig-oauth-audience-00.html) in JWT token. That claim's value should match to the `resourceId` value you specify your Spring app (if not specified it defaults to "oauth2-resource").

To fix your issue you need to:

1) Log into your shared UAA and make sure it does include "aud" claim.

2) Change the value of that "aud" claim to be "oauth2-resource" or preferably in your Spring app update `resourceId` to that claim's value like this:

```
    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
         resources.tokenServices(tokenServices());
         resources.resourceId(value from the aud claim you got from UAA server);
    }
```

Comment: Note: when using keycloak for the authorization server, the resourceId should be set to the client id. 

Thank you so much for your answer !!!!!!!

Comment: The above comment is the answer to this question.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the 2nd question `What is a resource id? Why do I need it and why does it cause the error above? Is that a Spring only thing??`. I can't find anything about the term `resource id`. I don't know why I need this, my client(frontend SPA) only send access token(not JWT, just plain random text).

Comment: It worked for me, I just needed to make sure, aud value (resource_ids value of oauth_client_details table) had to match with resources.resourceId(value_here).
thnks

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I already have the resources.resourceId call in my code and doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

I add a similar issue. In my case, I used jdbc authentification and my authorization server and resource server was two separate API.

- Authentorization server

  ```
     @Override
  public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) {
  oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
              .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
              .passwordEncoder(oauthClientPasswordEncoder);
  ```

  }

  ```
  /**
  * Define the client details service. The client may be define either as in memory or in database.
   * Here client with be fetch from the specify database
    */
  @Override
  public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
     clients.jdbc(dataSource);
  }

  /**
  * Define the authorization by providing authentificationManager
  * And the token enhancement
   */
   @Override
  public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
  endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore())
              .tokenEnhancer(getTokenEnhancer())
              .authenticationManager(authenticationManager).userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
   }
  ```
- Resource server

  ```
  public class OAuth2ResourceServerConfig extends 
      ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

      private TokenExtractor tokenExtractor = new BearerTokenExtractor();

      @Autowired
      private DataSource dataSource;

      @Bean
      public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
      }

       @Override
       public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
             http.addFilterAfter(new OncePerRequestFilter() {
             @Override
             protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
              FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
          // We don't want to allow access to a resource with no token so clear
          // the security context in case it is actually an OAuth2Authentication
          if (tokenExtractor.extract(request) == null) {
              SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
          }
          filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
      }
  }, AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class);
  http.csrf().disable();
  http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
   }

    @Bean
    public AccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
       return new DefaultAccessTokenConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public RemoteTokenServices remoteTokenServices(final @Value("${auth.server.url}") String checkTokenUrl,
      final @Value("${auth.resource.server.clientId}") String clientId,
      final @Value("${auth.resource.server.clientsecret}") String clientSecret) {

         final RemoteTokenServices remoteTokenServices = new RemoteTokenServices();
         remoteTokenServices.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl(checkTokenUrl);
         remoteTokenServices.setClientId(clientId);
         remoteTokenServices.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
        remoteTokenServices.setAccessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
  return remoteTokenServices;
     }
  ```

With this configuration, I was getting

```
    {
       "error": "access_denied",
       "error_description": "Invalid token does not contain resource id 
       (xxxxx)"
     }
```

To solve this, I had to add

```
    private String resourceIds= "xxxxx". !! maked sure that this resourceids is store in oauth_client_details for the clientid I used to get the token
    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
          resources.resourceId(resourceIds).tokenStore(tokenStore());
      }
```

Comment: Thanks, i was facing same issue

Comment: how to add it in request with bearer token, I am still facing same issue, I have already added this configurations.

Answer (score 2):

i faced same issue when i implment oauth2.0 with spring, here are what i found about resourceid.

Spring Security OAuth2 architecture is divided into Authorization Server and Resource Server resource server. We can set a ResourceID for each Resource Server (a microservice instance). When the Authorization Server grants authorization to a client, you can set which Resource Server resource services the client can access.

The purpose of configuring ResourceID for client in authorization server is to restrict the resource services that a client can access.

to set up ResourceID refere below link,
https://www.fatalerrors.org/a/resource-of-spring-security-oauth2_-id-configuration-and-verification.html